# MongoDB refusing to connect using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have been struggling to connect to MongoDB for the past few hours now.
I have taken the code from the atlas documentation as seen below:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')
const url =
    'mongodb+srv://user:pass@mmmcluster.axapu.mongodb.net/appname?retryWrites=true&w=majority&useNewUrlParser=true&useUnifiedTopology=true'
const client = new MongoClient(url)

async function run() {
    try {
        await client.connect()
        console.log('Connected correctly to server')
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.stack)
    } finally {
        await client.close()
    }
}

run().catch(console.dir)
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I keep getting the error below:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT 157.241.16.152:27017
at Timeout._onTimeout (E:\Documents\Github\@test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:306:38)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

For the record:

1. All IP addresses are whitelisted on my database access list
2. I have turned off any firewalls that would be running over the internet, and whitelisted NodeJS on the windows firewall
3. No spaces or brackets are have been included in my password or username
4. The user has admin privileges on atlas

Any suggestions? I am out of ideas here and I don't want to have to install Compass as a workaround since ideally, all methods of connection should work.

Comment: Have you ever tried the connect with exact connection string through Robo 3T or Compass ?

Comment: Where is your mongoDB database hosted? Did you try to connect using a database admin tool? Use [Canyouseeme](https://www.canyouseeme.org/) or another tool to check if the database port is opened. If all of this is fine, the problem will be code relatedly.

Comment: I have not tried either Robo 3T or Compass. I take that approach as a "sweeping it under the rug" type of thing. I was hoping to find a solution on here first before whipping out the broom

Comment: I do get an error showing my IP could not be seen on the given port specified in the Atlas documentation (21017). What should I do to rectify this? 

Also, I was trying to run all these connections of the terminal in VS Code, which I assume should be fine.

The DB is hosted in Bahrain if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score -1):

I think you should take a look here:

```
const url =
    'mongodb+srv://user:pass@mmmcluster.axapu.mongodb.net/appname?retryWrites=true&w=majority&useNewUrlParser=true&useUnifiedTopology=true'
```

since there is this `user` and `pass` you might want to replace them with the actual username and password for the database.

Comment: I have done that. I was not going to post the actual username and password :)